# Incompatibility between InfoPath 2007 WebServiceConnection and WCF

Tags: wcf, infopath, appfabric

I am trying to post data from InfoPath using the WebServiceConnection, to a WFC service inside of AppFabric.
The messgae never arrives in AppFabric, and I think I know why.
My WCF service is configured like this

```
<endpoint address="Workflow1.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WorkflowOperation" />
```

And when it is called by WCF Test Client, it generates the header

```
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/WorkflowOperation/ReceiveFormPayload</a:Action>
  </s:Header>
```

However, InfoPath does not generate this Soap header, it only generates the HTTP header

```
POST /Workflow1.xamlx HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/WorkflowOperation/ReceiveFormPayload"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
User-Agent: SOAP Toolkit 3.0
Host: localhost:51842
Content-Length: 1893
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

How do I configure my WCF endpoint to only need the HTTP-header action, and not the Soap Action?

Comment: Additional Information: It seems that InfoPath sends a soap envelope in the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ and AppFabric is expecting http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm back again, with the answer for anyone who is interested in getting InfoPath to submit data to an AppFabric service.

The .NET BasicHttpBinding uses a combination of Soap1.2+WSAddressing1.0 - while the InfoPath client will ONLY submit to web services using Soap1.1 (with NO WSAddressing support) - rending the two completely incompatible.
I actually ended up having to write an intermediary broker which would adapt the invocations.

Many thanks to "[codemeit](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/soap11-vs-soap12-wsaddressing.html)" for a very descriptive page of the composition of the various WCF binding types.